# JMS, MQ Exception in WebSphere

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ejb-3.1

I am getting this exception when I am trying to read message from WebSphere MQ via MDB, can any one please guide me.When I deploy the EAR file on my WebSphere then it works flawlessly but I am getting exception on a different WebSphere. Am I missing something in configuration, why does this exception occur?

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.jms.ConnectionFactory field com.ultramatics.hawkeye.mdb.listener.HawkeyeMdbListener.replyCF to com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously trying to assign a ConnectionFactory field with a MQQueue object, two different types.

I guess you grab them from JNDI or similar and that there might be some naming mess up in the configuration?

Comment: yes thanxs, there was naming mess up with (JNDI) configuration. Resolved :)